# LogisticRegression() vs LogisticRegressionCV() and its Cs hyper-parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've built a model using `LogisticRegression()` and after a grid search the data suggests for my inverse of regularization strength, `C = .0000001` is the "best" value to make my predictions.

This parameter works fine for `LogisticRegression()`, but seeing as I want to cross-validate I decide to use `LogisticRegressionCV()` the equivalent `c` parameter here is denoted as `Cs`, yet when I try to pass the same variable `Cs = .0000001`, I get an error:

```
    797     warm_start_sag = {"coef": np.expand_dims(w0, axis=1)}
    799 coefs = list()
--> 800 n_iter = np.zeros(len(Cs), dtype=np.int32)
    801 for i, C in enumerate(Cs):
    802     if solver == "lbfgs":

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

When referring to the [documents](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) it seems that for `LogisticRegressionCV()`:

> If Cs is as an int, then a grid of Cs values are chosen in a
> logarithmic scale between 1e-4 and 1e4.

How would I then still input a value of Cs = .0000001? I'm confused about how to proceed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using a very complex model? Your high regularization strength caught my eye (assuming you're basically doing l2=1e6, since C is inverse of l2 which is the default penalty term).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LogisticRegressionCV` is not meant to be just cross-validation-scored logistic regression; it is a hyperparameter-tuned (by cross-validation) logistic regression. That is, it tries several different regularization strengths, and selects the best one using cross-validation scores (then refits a single model on the entire training set, using that best `C`).  `Cs` can be a list of values to try for `C`, or an integer to let sklearn create a list for you (as in your quoted doc).

If you just want to score your model with fixed `C`, use `cross_val_score` or `cross_validate`.

(You probably *can* use `LogisticRegressionCV`, setting `Cs=[0.0000001]`, but it's not the right semantic usage.)